# Can a single Meteor instance listen and react to multiple MongoDB databases?

Tags: meteor

I would like to build a network of distributed Meteor apps that each share some parts of their Mongo database with each other.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this by changing how you define the collection on the server side using:

```
var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("<other mongo url>");

MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("collection_name", { _driver: database });
```

Comment: I'd actually recommend using the connection option on the collection to ddp.connect() to another instance where that instance is a standalone common app that all other apps connect to for common operations. This would be much more versatile, at least official, where there is no need for an undocumented internal api. Would you agree? I'd really like to hear your comments on this.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy I would agree with this previously, but the overhead if the intent to use many databases is a meteor app per db, which is quite heavy. Additionally there are several issues with this including `update` requiring _id as the query, allow/deny being rules being in effect and a couple of bugs (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1643) where `insert`,`update`,`remove` and queries with sort/limit have issues. The undocumented api makes this all seamless and simple.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy so if you use the ddp.connect way, from the client of the server where you do this can't have `MyCollection.update` without a `404 method not found` error. The current server to server ddp implementation is still quite buggy with Meteor. I struggled with this issue myself (and reported that bug in the link on github too in the comment above). If I had this method of directly using another mongodb url it would have been so much easier then

Comment: I thought of an architecture where all apps had their separate db's but only this common app to connect to for certain common queries, but yes, after reading through issue 1643, it seems more problem than convenience. Thank you very very much for these important pointers.